# Passenger module fails to install

Tags: rvm, passenger

On Mac OSX 10.8.4, I'm running:

```
sudo passenger-install-apache2-module
```

which suggested:

```
Your RVM wrapper scripts are too old, or some wrapper scripts are missing. Please update/regenerate them first by running:

rvmsudo rvm get stable && rvm reload && rvmsudo rvm repair all

If that doesn't seem to work, please run:

rvmsudo rvm wrapper [] --no-prefix --all
```

I did the first bit, re-ran the passenger-install-apache2-module but got the same problem. Then I did the second part. This gave:

```
awk: nonterminated character class ^[]=
source line number 1
context is
 >>> /^[]=/ <<< 
sed: 1: "s#^[]=##
": unbalanced brackets ([])
Unknown ruby interpreter string component: '[]'.
Could not load ruby [].
```

Any suggestions on where I go from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just run `passenger-install-apache2-module` do not prefix it with `sudo`.

the command will tell you what to do if it has no write access into required locations.

using `sudo` losses all environment variables - which basically breaks what rvm set up.

if you would really need root privileges you should use `rvmsudo` which does preserve all required environment variables.

Comment: Phusion Passenger 4.0.20 now checks whether 'sudo' was used instead of 'rvmsudo', and suggests using 'rvmsudo'.

Comment: See https://github.com/phusion/passenger/commit/c62462cae1e31eca988ca3c7ac6da19a8b669332. The `[]` that the user saw was Phusion Passenger trying to print an empty array. While fixing that, I discovered that certain environment variables are not available when run under 'sudo'. So by checking for that I can determine whether the user invoked 'sudo' or 'rvmsudo'.